Regex SQL to Pull Consecutive Numbers
I want to query only phone number with criteria triple repeated digit and at least repeated double digit from the following data.



phone_number




8181122274


8218241857


8178924294


8198884442



I tried this regex function:
WHERE phone_number REGEXP '(.)\\1{2}' AND msisdn REGEXP '(.)\\1{1}'

but it seems invalid, if the query was correct it should only pull:

8181122274
8198884442

a correct where conditions and explanation

You can attempt to match
^\d*(?:(\d)\1{2}\d*(\d)\2|(\d)\3\d*(\d)\4{2})

There will be a match if there is one sequence of length three of the same digit and another (separate) sequence of length two of the same digit. The two sequences can have the same repeated digit, but they may not overlap.
Demo
The expression has the following tokens.
^        # match beginning of the string
\d*      # match zero or more digits
(?:      # begin a non-capture group
  (\d)   # match a digit and save to capture group 1
  \1{2}  # match contents of capture group 1 twice
  \d*    # match zero or more digits
  (\d)   # match a digit and save to capture group 2
  \2     # match contents of capture group 2
|        # or
  (\d)   # match a digit and save to capture group 3
  \3     # match contents of capture group 3
  \d*    # match zero or more digits
  (\d)   # match a digit and save to capture group 4
  \4{2}  # match contents of capture group 4 twice
)        # end non-capture group


db<>fiddle working with all the backslashes doubled

@user1191247, I'm sure the asker will appreciate your comment.
